# Ruby on Rails syntax question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm a super newbie in RoR. Right now I'm working on this interesting Rails for Zombies exercises. And I got stuck with some syntax questions...

My code to this is:

```
Weapon.where(:zombie => "Ash")
```

But it won't work. If instead I typed:

```
Weapon.find(1)
```

I passed (since the first weapon belongs to the zombie Ash anyway).

**My question is, what's wrong with my answer with this .where() method?**

Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Here is the link to the tutorial, for those interested: http://railsforzombies.org/

Comment: Thanks for asking the question. I got stuck at the same part and the responses here (especially those of ravi and DGM) explained the reason for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should have nested the query as follows:

```
Weapon.where(:zombie => {:name => "Ash"})
```

That would give you the *weapons that belong to the zombies whose names are 'Ash'*

Comment: This looks hopeful to me... :)

Answer (score 4):

If, like me, you were trying to attempt this via the Zombie Model, you will need to use **first** method. This is because **where()** returns a collection of Zombies.

i.e.

```
Zombie.where(:name => "Ash").first.weapons
```

This tutorial still teaches the old hash syntax, but ever since Ruby 1.9 you can (and should) use the new simplified format. This syntax even works in the Zombies tutorial:

```
Zombie.where(name:"Ash").first.weapons
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want a where clause you 
Now returns a single value then you could write

```
Zombie.where(:name => "ash").first
```

Comment: I dont think so, since question asks for "all"

Comment: @Chris Actually this does work, you just need to add .weapons to the end of it to join the Weapons model.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, also new to Rails3 queries, but doesnt **:zombie** expect to match a zombie object, not its name.

I would do `Zombie.where(:name => "Ash").weapons`

Comment: thanks Chris. but it seems that the *weapons* relationship was not set up in the Zombie class (while it should be). so I got a "#<NoMethodError: undefined method `weapons' for ..." error

Comment: Try `Zombie.where(:name => "Ash").weapon` if it's a one to one relationship.

Answer (score 2):

You generally use `Model.find( )` if a single object is needed and it returns nil if not found. Whereas `Model.where({:field => value})` returns an array of objects those matches the condition.

Comment: Just a nitpick: Technically, in rails 3, it does not return an array. It returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` (which conceptually is a collection of items, but no query has been made yet).   Rails 3 lets you chain these relations together, and you only get an answer when you call find_all or each or similar.  Even then the result is not an array, but an enumerator.

Answer (score 2):

This is how they intend you to do it (based on the video)

ash = Zombie.find(1)
ash.weapons

Which should return an array of all the weapons ash owns.  I tried for so long to use the count method and then I realized they just wanted the actual weapon items (array/list/whatever it is I'm just starting rails from a c++ and python background)

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same problem today but the accepted answer didn't work for me. I don't know whether the API has changed since 2010 but I got it to work by doing this:

```
Weapon.joi­ns(:zombie­).where(:z­ombies => {:nam­e => "Ash"­})
```

You can also get the same result by joining in the other direction although I think the first solution is what the question was looking for:

```
Zombie.whe­re(:name => 'Ash'­).first.we­apons
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the zombie table is linked to the weapon table, you can use the following code:
Zombie.find(1).weapons.all

FYI - Zombie ID 1 = Ash

Answer (score 1):

> Weapon.where(:zombie_id => '1')
>   => [#]

Answer (score 1):

```
Zombie.where(:name => "Ash").first.weapons
```

IMHO: I think that this way is more explicit: first, we are looking for a zombie, and then - want to take the first one's weapon.

Surely, you *can* look for the Weapon by zombie's id (Weapon.where(:zombie_id => SOME_ZOMBIE_ID)), BUT as for me - this is not the thing I want to see in my code half a year after - it is about more coding and wasting more time for understanding.

ps: Seems that my answer is a shorter version of Gerry's answer (see above) - sorry for that :)

Answer (score 1):

In this context u can try this code:

```
z = Zombie.find("ID")
Weapon.where(:zombie_id => z)
```

Comment: and for the next exercise if u wanna count all the Weapons that belongs to "Ash" u simple type: 

    z.weapons.count

Answer (score 1):

```
Weapon.whe­re(:zombie­_id => Zombi­e.where(:n­ame => "Ash"­))
```

You can select from DB Weapon, the `zombie_id` which name is Ash from DB Zombie.

Answer (score 0):

I think you passed using `Weapon.find(1)` because there was only one weapon in the weapons table, but if you create another weapon, with the :id => 1 then your original syntax wouldn't work - cause it only returned the first weapon and not all the weapons.

I passed using, `Zombie.find(1).weapons` which will return multiple entries for weapons associated with :id = 1, but was also thinking the same as you and wanted to search by :name and not :id.

I was also thinking about using the "where" attribute, but can't get it to work - and when I used @edgerunner answer it returned:

```
#<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: zombie.name: SELECT "weapons".* FROM "weapons" WHERE "zombie"."name" = 'Ash'>
```

so I'm not sure if this is a limitation through the program or what - as it is, im still bit confused.

Comment: ' Zombie.find_by_name('Ash').weapons' works and uses the name attribute, but i dont think **find_by_name** has been yet discussed

Answer (score 0):

the answers is `Zombie.find(1).weapons` .. then **you will success to find all Ash's weapons.**